Finding kernel headers with cmake
I need to include <asm/barrier.h> and <asm/msr.h>. I see them (in /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-27/arch/x86/include/asm but cmake doesn't. I tried:
  find_path(KERNELHEADERS_DIR
    include/asm/barrier.h
  )

...and:
execute_process(
  COMMAND uname -r
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE KERNEL_RELEASE
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)

string(REPLACE "-generic" "" KERNEL_RELEASE  "${KERNEL_RELEASE}")

# Find the headers
find_path(KERNELHEADERS_DIR
  include/asm/barrier.h
  PATHS /usr/src/linux-headers-${KERNEL_RELEASE}
)

...and variations thereof, but it stubbornly returns /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-28-generic.
I don't need a super complete solution, I just need it to work on Ubuntu (it's for YOMM2's benchmarks, not a public, documented thing).
Help?
[edit]
I tried again, following  @tsyvarev's suggestions, but it doesn't work, even when I specify the literal path to the headers:
$ ls -l /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-27/arch/x86/include/asm/barrier.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2939 Aug 27  2023 /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-27/arch/x86/include/asm/barrier.h

find_path(
  KERNEL_INCLUDE_DIR
  asm/barrier.h
  PATHS /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-27/arch/x86
)
message(STATUS "KERNEL_INCLUDE_DIR = ${KERNEL_INCLUDE_DIR}")

KERNEL_INCLUDE_DIR = KERNEL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND


Why search a header with find_path when you already know the header location? Just add directory /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-27/arch/x86/include to the include directories of your executable/library.

Because I want it to work on different machines running different versions of ubuntu. True, I could use the second option and skip find_path altogether. I might end up doing that.  Surely there is a better way - and something new to learn today. But I already spent an hour on this.

Do not expect CMake to find your header without any hints. By default CMake only checks those directories which system reports as ones to contain headers suitable for user space programs. Files from the Linux kernel tree (which you have under /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-27), are NOT intended to be used anywhere outside of the Linux kernel and its modules. So your system won't report a directory from that tree as one for search. Well, you could hint find_path with a desired directory (as you already do), so find_path will check existence of the header.

"I need to include <asm/barrier.h> ..." - So you should specify that relative path for the find_path command: find_path(KERNELHEADERS_DIR asm/barrier.h). On success find_path returns (via variable) a directory which contain given relative path. Your specification of PATHS should contain possible values for such directory. E.g. /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-27/arch/x86/include.

Reply in question.

After hard-coding the paths, I ran into trouble whie trying to include those headers in a normal program (redefinitions etc), but I found my way to <x86intrin.h>.

"I tried again, following @tsyvarev's suggestions" - Please, re-read my suggestion. In my previous comment I suggested to use /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-27/arch/x86/include as PATHS argument. Your attempt uses the path without /include suffix.
